# unsupported_grant_type type error on JWT_BEARER strategy of OAuth2 Server Java Spring

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I have this client registered in the config:

```
RegisteredClient registeredClientJwt = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        // .clientSettings(ClientSettings.builder().requireAuthorizationConsent(false).build())
        .clientId("jwt-client")
        .clientSecret("{noop}jwt-secret")
        .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.PRIVATE_KEY_JWT)
        .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.JWT_BEARER)
        // .tokenSettings(TokenSettings.builder().accessTokenTimeToLive(Duration.ofDays(1)).build())
        .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
        .scope("lms.read")
        .build();
```

And I am following `grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer` strategy, but it says `unsupported_grant_type` error and states that grand type is not supported.

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? I have facing the same problem and I did not find any solution for this

Comment: No, I gave up on this. I don't remember now exactly, but I think it was about the [OAuth2.1](https://oauth.net/2.1) protocol change. Grant-type support was removed.